# Tweepy Stream: Retweets as full text

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Having trouble finding a solution to print all tweets in my stream as "full_text", aka non-truncated tweets. Retweets seem to be the problem, but I cannot get my code to get full_text for all tweets. Or, do I need to rethink the solution, and make a second stream class just for retweets?

Suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import json
import datetime    
import re
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import sys
import os
import tweepy
import string
import subprocess
import unicodedata as ud
from tweepy import Stream, StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler, AppAuthHandler
from tweepy import API

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('', '')
auth.set_access_token('', '')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        results = status.text.encode('UTF8')
        print (results)
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            return False

stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener, tweet_mode='extended')
stream.filter(track=["twitter", "syria"])
```

Answer (score -1):

While using stream seemed like a good idea, the api search has more robust options. Using api search I was able to get the "full_text" of tweets and retweets by using:

```
tweet._json['full_text']
```

Next step is figuring out how to display 'name' as well as full text. Simply using the following does not work:

```
tweet._json['full_text', 'name']
```